# C++ Class into C++ DLL into C# Windows Forms Class

Tags: c#, c++, dll

I want to use my c++ class in c# windows forms application.

I made a c++ class in the header files (.h and .cpp) then i made a win32 project where it should become a dll.

Then i want to use it in my c# windows forms project but i dont know where to put it or what to put.

[This is the StackLibrary.h and .cpp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N7HWJ.png)

[This is what i have in the c# windows forms project, i added the interopservices and the dllimport. i dont know what to do next or if its correct. pls help.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zRLeT.png)

Comment: [STAThread] belongs to Main method, you cannot separate it. Write DllImport above STAThread.

Comment: How do i use the functions after writing the DllImport above the STAThread?

Comment: Below DllImport, you must write the function name, see example : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: what about for the constructors in the class? it says it must have return type but its a constructor

Comment: See Answer, someone already answer it. It is easier to create a C++ .NET project. Make a function there to call all your methods. Then call this function from C#.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write a wrapper in C++/CLI (rif. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235281.aspx):
Writing the wrapper in C++, compiling as a DLL using C++/CLI then adding to your C# project you will have no errors:

StackLibrary DLL (native c++) <-> wrapper DLL (c++/cli) <-> C# project

Comment: should i replace the stacklibrary dll with a wrapper?

Comment: You can keep them separate: this way you can use your StackLibrary DLL both in c# (via wrapper) and with other languages (e.g. C++, VB, php, ... and all languages that can import DLL). You can transform the StackLibrary project adding the wrapper and compiling with C++/CLI option. In this case (stacklibrary dll replacement) you will be able to add this DLL to .Net/Mono project only.